# How to avoid code redundancy with JAVA generics

Tags: java, generics

I have two similar functions which send different requests to different APIs:

```java
// fill request
CompletableFuture<ReqType1> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
RpcClientController rpcClientController = new RpcClientController();
service1.api1(rpcClientController, request1, future::complete);
RspType1 response;
try {
    if (rpcClientController.isFailed()) {
        log.error();
        return null;
    }
    response = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (response == null) {
        log.error();
        return null;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
// process response
```

The other:

```java
// fill request
CompletableFuture<ReqType2> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
RpcClientController rpcClientController = new RpcClientController();
service2.api2(rpcClientController, request2, future::complete);
RspType2 response;
try {
    if (rpcClientController.isFailed()) {
        log.error();
        return null;
    }
    response = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (response == null) {
        log.error();
        return null;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
// process response
```

A `template` method in C++ can handle this. I think C++ compiler creates two methods for <ReqType1, RspType1, SrvType1, ApiFunc1> and <ReqType2, RspType2, SrvType2, ApiFunc2>, respectively.

Nevertheless, this cannot be compiled properly in Java:

```java
protected <Request, Service, Response> 
Response callService(Request request, Service service, Response response) {
    ...
    service.api1(rpcClientController, request, future::complete); 
    // wrong, cannot resolve method 'api1' in 'service'
}
```

It seems that generic type `Service` is the same as `Object` to Java compiler. So what does a generic method usually look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close with this, the way you've declared your type parameters is incorrect though. It should be more like:

```
protected <T extends Request, S extends Service, R extends Response> 
Response callService(T request, S service, R response) {
    ...
    service.api1(rpcClientController, request, future::complete); 
}
```

By convention in Java type parameters are a single uppercase letter. To get them to behave as you expect you need to bound the types; hence the `extends`.

Comment: So if ReqType1 and ReqType2 extend different super classes, or their super has no method 'setField(int)', generics cannot be used even though ReqType1.setField(int) and ReqType2.setField(int) both exist?

Comment: Yeah that's right. The super class they extend in the type bound doesn't have to be a class, it can be an interface if that helps? You still use the extends keyword for type bounds though.